# Dividing float numbers with 2 decimal places vs same float numbers with 6 decimal places

Tags: math, floating-point, statistics

We have 2 float numbers with 6 decimal places. We are dividing them and showing the result on our web page. We are also showing the 2 numbers we used for division on the web page. As those 2 numbers are very long (with 6 decimal places), we thought it may not be a good user experience to show the full numbers. So we decided to show those numbers only up to 2 decimal places. But this is confusing for users as they are dividing those 2 numbers and trying to match with the result which is different (as calculated using full numbers).

Example - Let's say there are 2 numbers : 0.289045 and 0.017457. If we divide these numbers, the result is 16.56 which is show to users along with those 2 numbers as 0.28 and 0.01. Now users trying to divide 0.28 and 0.01 and the result they get is 28 which is not matching with what we are showing.

We thought may be showing 28 (that is dividing 0.28 and 0.01) is the right approach. But this doesn't work for numbers like 0.289045 and 0.001745. Here, dividing 0.28 with 0.00 would not give any result. And we always want to show positive results to users.

I am not able to think of a right approach to tackle this problem. What could be the correct way?

Comment: What language are you using? What is the code you are using?

Comment: What language are you using? I know that javascript has some limitations with decimal places. Maybe when dealing with fixed decimal places, you should multiply the number to the 10ish number that allow you to do math operations with integers. (Of course will not work for infinite floating point numbers without rounding ex: 1/3 = 0.333333....)

Answer (score 0):

You could present all the numbers with 2 or 3 significant digits instead of a fixed number of decimals.

e.g.

```
0.28 / 0.017 = 16
```

or

```
0.289 / 0.0174 = 16.6
```

Comment: This could be one approach. But then if the numbers are something like 0.289045 and 0.000175. We would end up showing 0.00017 which is almost same as showing full number.

Comment: Another alternative would be to switch to scientific notation. 0.17 * 10 ^-3 slightly more cluttered to look at, but at least it is easy to ensure the strings are always the same length